# display array values into select option tag in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display array values into select tag, but all the array values displayed as single value. Please see below logic I added. Data is dynamic, I am getting data from backend like this ["Sankranti", "Sankranti 1"].

```
const [eventNameList, setEventNameList] = useState([])

var eventList = eventNameList.length > 0 ? 
                eventNameList.map((item,i) => {
                    console.log('list: ', item)
                    return (
                        <option>{item}</option>
                        )
                    })
                    :
                    'No Events'
<select>
      {eventList}
</select>
```

please find below console screen shot

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you print `eventNameList` outside the loop and show be the result?

Comment: I think your result is nested array, that's why you are getting an array in a loop. Could you show us your result returned from api.

Comment: outside loop i added eventNameList. it displayed in console like this. eventNameList:  
[Array(2)]
0: (2) ["Sankranti", "Sankranti 1"]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your list is nested inside another `array` so to fix this you could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `map`

or you could just iterate throw the first `element` inside your nested `array`

```
const [eventNameList, setEventNameList] = useState([])

var eventList = eventNameList.length > 0 ? 
                eventNameList[0].map((item,i) => {
                    console.log('list: ', item)
                    return (
                        <option>{item}</option>
                        )
                    })
                    :
                    'No Events'
<select>
      {eventList}
</select>
```

Comment: I got same results previous results.

Comment: try this one instead of `flatMap` try `eventNameList[0].map`

Comment: Thanks this logic eventNameList[0].map worked. could you please let me how this logic works.

Comment: you are welcome :), because it returns a subarray that includes `[["Sankranti", "Sankranti 1"], "another data you do not need"]` so as you mention you want the list in the first index only that contains your `array` so you can access it by its index in the outer array